# Group periodic data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| idx | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/01 00:00:01 | 5 | 2 |
| 01/01/01 00:00:02 | 4 | 5 |
| 01/01/01 00:00:03 | 5 | 4 |
| 02/01/01 00:00:01 | 3 | 8 |
| 02/01/01 00:00:02 | 7 | 4 |
| 02/01/01 00:00:03 | 1 | 3 |

I would like to group data based on its periodicity such that the final dataframe is:

| new_idx | 01/01/01 | 02/01/01 | old_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00:01 | 5 | 3 | A |
| 00:00:02 | 4 | 7 | A |
| 00:00:03 | 5 | 1 | A |
| 00:00:01 | 2 | 8 | B |
| 00:00:02 | 5 | 4 | B |
| 00:00:03 | 4 | 3 | B |

Is there a way to this that holds when the first dataframe gets big (more columns, more periods and more samples)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to `melt` the DataFrame, then split the datetime to dates and times; finally `pivot` the resulting DataFrame for the final output:

```py
df = df.melt('idx', var_name='old_column')
df[['date','new_idx']] = df['idx'].str.split(expand=True)
out = df.pivot(['new_idx','old_column'], 'date', 'value').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=[None]).sort_values(by='old_column')
```

Output

```py
    new_idx old_column  01/01/01  02/01/01
0  00:00:01          A         5         3
2  00:00:02          A         4         7
4  00:00:03          A         5         1
1  00:00:01          B         2         8
3  00:00:02          B         5         4
5  00:00:03          B         4         3
```

Comment: Just learned a new technique,cool!